# How to hide the particular text in livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to see the particular lines where the replacements are takeing place. All other text should be in hidden format. Is it possible?

```
 on mouseUp
   put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml
   set the caseSensitive to true
   put the field SRText into myArrayToBe
   split myArrayToBe by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
   repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
      --return i
      put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
      split y by colon
      put y[1] into searchStr
      put y[2] into replaceStr
      if searchStr is empty then
         put the  0 into m
      else 
         replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtml
      end if
   end repeat
   set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
   end mouseUP
```

Comment: Are you the same as who has been posting lots of questions with syntax that uses arrays all the time? Really, you don't need to use an array. Please, stop using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are looking to do, but I think you don't want to 'replace' first. Dump your myHtml into "MytextField" and then use the find syntax in that field. It will scroll to the found text and draw a square around it then you can use the foundtext, foundline, foundchunk to do replace, highlight, dim all other text or whatever your after.